# resolve TypeError: req.flash is not a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes, passport.js

Working with Registration in a Site. For the register Form,Validation is done using mongoose models and trying to Use Flash to display the error message in the Form.

In my nodejs app it shows an error like:

> TypeError: req.flash is not a function

I have installed connection-flash npm it is throwing an error like:

> TypeError: req.flash is not a function at

> E:\node-course\apnadukan\src\routes\index.js:21:24

```
app.js

const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const hbs = require('hbs');
const flash = require("connect-flash");
const passport = require("passport");
const db = require('./connection/db');

// Express Use
const app = express()
const port = 3000;

// Form Data Get
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

// HBS Handlebar use
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

// Router Use
app.use('/', require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes/index.js')))
// Publics assess link (HBS)
const static_path = path.join(__dirname, '../publics');
app.use(express.static(static_path));
// View Set (HBS)
const views = path.join(__dirname, '../src/views');
const partials_path = path.join(__dirname, '../src/views/partials');
app.set('views', views);
hbs.registerPartials(partials_path);

// 
app.use(flash());
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());


app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})



index.js

const express = require('express');
const addUser = require('../models/register');
let passport = require("passport");
let LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
// const passport = require('../config/passport');
const {validationRegister, validationRegisterMsg} = require('../config/validator');




// const router = express.Router()
const router = require('express').Router()

router.get('/' , (req , res)=>{
res.render('index', {
title: "Welcome To Apna Dukan"
})
})
router.get('/welcome-to-apnadukan', (req , res)=>{
var errorMsg = req.flash('error')[0];
res.render('register', {
title: "Register | Welcome To Apna Dukan",
errorMsg,
page_name: "Register"
});
});
router.post('/welcome-to-apnadukan',
[
validationRegister(), 
validationRegisterMsg,
passport.authenticate("local.register", {
successRedirect: "/login",
failureRedirect: "/welcome-to-apnadukan",
failureFlash: true,
}),
], 
async (req , res)=>{
try {
if (req.session.oldUrl) {
let oldUrl = req.session.oldUrl;
req.session.oldUrl = null;
res.redirect(oldUrl);
} else {
res.redirect("/welcome-to-apnadukan");
}
    
} catch (error) {
req.flash("error", error.message);
res.status(400).send(error);
return res.redirect("/");
}
})

router.get('/login' , (req , res)=>{
res.render('login', {
title: "Login | Welcome To Apna Dukan",
page_name: "Login"
})
})
router.post('/login' , (req , res)=>{
req.send("Update");
})
router.get('/recover-password', (req, res)=>{
res.render('recoverpassword',{
title: "Recover Password | Welcome To Apna Dukan",
page_name: "Recover Password"
})
})
router.post('/recover-password', (req, res)=>{
res.render('recoverpassword',{
title: "Recover Password | Welcome To Apna Dukan",
page_name: "Recover Password"
})
})

router.get('/page' , (req , res)=>{
res.send('Hello World!')
})

module.exports  = router


Validator.js


const { check, validationResult } = require("express-validator");

const validationRegister = (()=>{
return [
check('name', 'Name is required').not().isEmpty(),
check('username', 'Username is required').not().isEmpty().matches('/^(?![0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/').withMessage('Only AlphaNumeric character is allowed').isLength({min:6,max:6}).withMessage('Minimum 6 characters required'),
check('email', 'Email is required').not().isEmpty().isEmail().withMessage('Email must be a valid email address.'),
check('password', 'Password is required').not().isEmpty().matches('/^(?=(.*[a-zA-Z].*){2,})(?=.*\d.*)(?=.*\W.*)[a-zA-Z0-9\S]{6,}$/').withMessage('Strong passwords with min 6  characters, at least two letters (not case sensitive), one number, one special character, space is not allowed'),
];
});
const validationRegisterMsg = (req, res, next)=>{
const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
let messages = [];
errors.array().forEach((error)=>{
    messages.push(error.msg)
});
req.flash('error', messages);
// req.flash({error: messages})
return res.redirect('/register');
}
next();
};

module.exports = {validationRegister,validationRegisterMsg};


passport.js

const passport = require("passport");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const User = require("../models/register");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
User.findById(id, (err, user) => {
done(err, user);
});
});

passport.use(
"local.register",
new LocalStrategy(
{
nameField: 'name',
usernameField: 'username',
emailField: 'email',
passwordField: 'password',
passReqToCallBack: true
},
async (req, username, email, done) => {
try {
const username = await Customer_users.findOne({ username: username });
if (username) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Username already exists" });
}
const user = await Customer_users.findOne({ email: email });
if (user) {
    return done(null, false, { message: "Email already exists" });
}
const newUser = await new User();
newUser.name = name;
newUser.username = username;
newUser.email = email;
newUser.password = newUser.encryptPassword(password);
await newUser.save();
return done(null, newUser);
} catch (error) {
console.log(error);
return done(error);
}
}
)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are configuring flash in your app after configuring the routes.
Moving this line `app.use(flash());` before line `app.use('/', require(path.join(__dirname, 'routes/index.js')));` will resolve the issue.